# how can i optimize this mysql query ? i use OR operator

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

i got a mysql query like this:

```
select a.goods_id, 
       a.site_id,
       b.goods_name,
       a.cost,
       a.stock 
from rs_goods as a 
inner join rs_goods_multi as b 
   on a.goods_id = b.goods_id 
where a.goods_sn LIKE 'sweater005%' 
OR    b.goods_name LIKE 'sweater005%';
```

and it shows type 'ALL', maybe the 'OR' cause it, how can i optimize it, i had add index for field 'goods_sn' and 'goods_name'. You can see the mysql capture below.[mysql capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sElkO.jpg)

Comment: do you have indexes on `a.goods_sn` and `b.goods_name` ?

Comment: yes，i add index for this two fields

Comment: Do you have to use a wildcard (%)? or can you just search for the exact product name ?

Comment: i think the problem is the OR operator ,

Comment: what do u mean by type 'ALL' ?

Comment: it means the mysql scan all table, not using index

Comment: can you please post the DDL?

Comment: it doesn't show the full explain output. We can't determine if it's actually doing what it's supposed to do if you don't show the entire explain output

Comment: ya sorry, didnt see image. Problem is, when u use `%` the whole table is scanned ie row by row scanning for matching. As @FMashiro suggested, try to find exact words without `%` or modify schema and query to find y ID

Comment: Please improve the way you ask your question by formatting it.
I couldn't understand it after reading 3 times.

Comment: @marijnz0r sorry, i'm a green hand for here.  u can see the image, i just want to know why the table still not using index but scanning all table when i have index for those two fields(a.goods_sn,b.goods_name)

Comment: @PrabhatG , if i use % like "%field%", it may cause all table scanning, but if i put the % operator behind the field like 'field%' , it should use index to quey

Comment: The query optimizer is making a choice. It needs to join tables a to b, using a primary key, and it also needs to do the text search. MySQL uses only one index per table, and it's deciding that there isn't an index that is selective enough to work. I'd experiment with compound indexes on both tables, with the primary key and the text field; you may need to change the order for the optimizer to pick it up.

Comment: Could you try and add the tables to your question? Using this: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION to remove the OR from your query and you can generally get much better results, as each query can use a single index effectively.

```
select a.goods_id, 
       a.site_id,
       b.goods_name,
       a.cost,
       a.stock 
from rs_goods as a 
inner join rs_goods_multi as b 
   on a.goods_id = b.goods_id 
where a.goods_sn LIKE 'sweater005%' 
UNION
select a.goods_id, 
       a.site_id,
       b.goods_name,
       a.cost,
       a.stock 
from rs_goods as a 
inner join rs_goods_multi as b 
   on a.goods_id = b.goods_id 
where b.goods_name LIKE 'sweater005%'
```

See if this gives better results.